# REST client with expiring JWT and eclipse micro-profile

Tags: java, rest, quarkus, microprofile

I'm writing a micro-service with quarkus and eclipse micro-profile. Part of it is reading some configuration from an REST endpoint with a simple GET. So far so easy.

The webservice endpoint needs JWT authentication. To get the token I've to call another endpoint with basic HTTP authentication. The server does not use a standard like OAuth or OpenID. I only find micro-profile examples without or only basic authentication.

So my question is, how can I implement that process with micro-profile? I need to authenticate first, put that JWT header into the RestRequest and be aware of the expiration. Maybe there is some help in the framework?

Thank you

Comment: If you downvote could you please write a comment?

Answer (score 1):

If your auth provider uses a custom auth scheme, then you will have to write your own ClientRequestFilter that handles the process of obtaining the JWT and then passing it to the original request as auth header.
You can have a look at existing Quarkus OIDC client filter [here](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/2.3/extensions/oidc-client-filter/runtime/src/main/java/io/quarkus/oidc/client/filter/OidcClientRequestFilter.java)

- basically you need to implement the `getAccessToken` method, where you would make a request to your Auth endpoint, exchange hard credentials for a token, and then use the obtained token. To improve performance, you should store the tokens in a cache/AtomicReference with clientctx as key, so you can reuse them if they are not expired on subsequente requests.